# VaultInvalidConfigError: How can I add a simple config to TypeScripts's vault-api?

Tags: typescript, hashicorp-vault

Vault itself endorses [vault-api](https://github.com/SaiHemanthBR/vault-api/wiki/Configs#default-values) as an official TypeScript library for using Vault

I only want to retrieve a value from one the the KV pairs that I store in Vault. I know VAULT_ADDR and VAULT_TOKEN and the path to the KV pair (respectively stored in `.env`,`.env`, ts file)

When the following is run

```
const Value = await vault({
      method: 'read',
      path: '.../.../.../KEY',
    })
```

I get

```
VaultInvalidConfigError: Vault: Missing required configuration
{
  "address": "https://....com:8200",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "token": "hvs...",
  "headers": {},
  "isVaultRequest": true,
  "method": "read",
  "path": ".../.../.../KEY"
}
    at Vault._vault (/.../node_modules/vault-api/dist/core/vault.js:37:19)
```

The source code throws the Error because I don't provide an `engine` property but according to the library [author](https://github.com/SaiHemanthBR/vault-api/wiki/Configs#default-configs), this is optional

I tried adding a default `engine`:

```
const Key = await vault({
      method: 'read',
      path: '.../.../.../KEY',
      engine: getEngineName
    })
```

but the same error arises